# carousel in Semantic UI not available

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I am wondering, I did not find **carousel** component in Semantic UI.
I feel it is very common and useful component.

I know one option [OWL Carouse](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html). I do not want to use jQuery, though for Semantic UI I will just include jQuery. Rest of the things I want to achieve via Angular.

I need to know the possible options without writing jQuery code.

Answer (score 6):

Semantic UI evidently does not currently have a carousel module, and it is an [open issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/962).

There are, however, some small snippets on that page that can achieve what you'd like to. See [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and [Swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative.

[fotorama.io](http://fotorama.io/)

Answer (score 0):

yes there is no carousel in Semantic UI at moment but you can use cards somewhat similar here is one I found to be closest to bootstrap carousel;

```
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="ui slide masked reveal image">
    <img src="/images/avatar/large/jenny.jpg" class="visible content">
    <img src="/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg" class="hidden content">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="header">Team Fu &amp; Hess</a>
    <div class="meta">
      <span class="date">Created in Sep 2014</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <a>
      <i class="users icon"></i>
      2 Members
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps, 
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link you can create a coursel in semantic ui.
https://codesandbox.io/s/43pv7wm6n9

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Your answer must contain an example in code ...
After all, this question is old ...